# I want to send the filtered data to my mail from the Database

Tags: php, email

I have written the code for Filter the data from Database and send the result via mail. Its sending the mail, but its sending separate mails for each row displaying in the result. I want the result in a single mail. I have share the code iam using now.

```php
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DBNAME";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_phone, user_email FROM registers WHERE status='0'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows = "id: " . $row["user_id"] . " - Name: " . $row["user_phone"] . " " . $row["user_email"];
        echo "$rows";


        $to = "******@gmail.com";
        $subject = "My subject";
        $txt = "$rows";
        $headers = "From: admin@******.com" . "\r\n" .
            "CC: ***********@gmail.com";

        mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: just move `mail` call outside of while loop.

Comment: @rksosegi true but slightly more will be required as well, to ensure all the rows are included

Comment: Hello rkosegi. if i move the mail call outside the while loop, its sending the last row from the result. Actually the result have 5 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use `.=` to concatenate onto the `txt` variable, and then move the `mail` stuff outside of the loop.

```php
    $txt = '';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows = "id: " . $row["user_id"] . " - Name: " . $row["user_phone"] . " " . $row["user_email"];
        echo "$rows";
        
        $txt .= $rows . "\r\n";
    }

    $to = "******@gmail.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $headers = "From: admin@******.com" . "\r\n" .
        "CC: ***********@gmail.com";

    mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to create variable to capture your rows:

```
$rows = "";
```

Next, inside the while loop, store values into this `$rows` variable:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row = "id: " . $row["user_id"] . " - Name: " . $row["user_phone"] . " " . $row["user_email"];
    $rows .= $row . "\n";
    echo "$row\n";
}
```

Finally, move the `mail()` to outside loop:

```
$to = "******@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "$rows";
$headers = "From: admin@******.com" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: ***********@gmail.com";

mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$txt="";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$rows = "id: " . $row["user_id"]. " - Name: " . $row["user_phone"]. " " . $row["user_email"];

$txt.=$row."\r\n"; }

$to = "******@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$headers = "From: admin@******.com" . "\r\n" . "CC: ***********@gmail.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers); }
$conn->close();
```